# Reverse geocoding in R

Tags: r

I have ugandan health facility csv file with longitudes and latitudes and my objective is to get the name of each facility, subcounty, parish and village.

When i tried reverse geocode function i just got the address is there way i get the names of the facility, subcounty, parish and villages

```
install.packages('tidygeocoder')
install.packages("tidyverse")
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(tidygeocoder)
library(tidyverse)

# import the Health facilities into RStudio
HealthFacilties <- read_csv("~/myproject/HealthFacilties.csv")
HealthFacilties %>% mutate(longitude = Long, latitide = Lat)
#class(HealthFacilties)
#typeof(HealthFacilties)

#Get the locations
healthfacilities_reverse_geocode <- HealthFacilties %>% 
  reverse_geocode(lat = Lat, long = Long, method = "arcgis")
```

Comment: Please provide some examples. Paste the output of `dput(head(HealthFacilties))` as text. Please mention the CRS.

Answer (score 0):

Use Nominatim, it returns all administrative levels up to country. In below example data (points) are taken from OSM for `amenity = doctors`.

Substitute `poi` with your coordinates. {tmaptools} used for reverse geocoding.

```r
b <- osmdata::getbb("Uganda")
a <- osmdata::opq(b, timeout = 60*20) |>
  osmdata::add_osm_feature(key = "amenity", value = "doctors") |>
  osmdata::osmdata_sf()

poi <- a$osm_points[1:10, "amenity"=='doctors'] |>
  sf::st_coordinates()

tmaptools::rev_geocode_OSM(x=poi[2, "X"], y = poi[2, "Y"])
#> [[1]]
#> [[1]]$x
#>        X 
#> 34.37019 
#> 
#> [[1]]$y
#>       Y 
#> 1.01434 
#> 
#> [[1]]$name
#> [1] "Bukigai Health Centre, Bududa Ring, Bukigai, Bugisa sub-region, Bududa, Eastern Region, Uganda"
#> 
#> [[1]]$place_id
#> [1] "36369302"
#> 
#> [[1]]$osm_type
#> [1] "node"
#> 
#> [[1]]$osm_id
#> [1] "542507954"
#> 
#> [[1]]$ref
#> [1] "Bukigai Health Centre"
#> 
#> [[1]]$lat
#> [1] 1.01434
#> 
#> [[1]]$lon
#> [1] 34.37019
#> 
#> [[1]]$lat_min
#> [1] 1.01429
#> 
#> [[1]]$lat_max
#> [1] 1.01439
#> 
#> [[1]]$lon_min
#> [1] 34.37014
#> 
#> [[1]]$lon_max
#> [1] 34.37024
#> 
#> [[1]]$amenity
#> [1] "Bukigai Health Centre"
#> 
#> [[1]]$road
#> [1] "Bududa Ring"
#> 
#> [[1]]$village
#> [1] "Bukigai"
#> 
#> [[1]]$county
#> [1] "Bugisa sub-region"
#> 
#> [[1]]$state
#> [1] "Bududa"
#> 
#> [[1]]$`ISO3166-2-lvl4`
#> [1] "UG-218"
#> 
#> [[1]]$region
#> [1] "Eastern Region"
#> 
#> [[1]]$`ISO3166-2-lvl3`
#> [1] "UG-E"
#> 
#> [[1]]$country
#> [1] "Uganda"
#> 
#> [[1]]$country_code
#> [1] "ug"
```

<sup>Created on 2024-01-30 with [reprex v2.1.0](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

EDIT:

The similar results can be achieved with your {tidygeocoder} package:

```r
> tidygeocoder::reverse_geo(long = poi[, "X"], lat = poi[, "Y"], method = "osm")
Passing 10 coordinates to the Nominatim single coordinate geocoder
[============================================================================================] 10/10 (100%) Elapsed: 10s Remaining:  0s
# A tibble: 10 × 3
     lat  long address                                                                                                                   
   <dbl> <dbl> <chr>                                                                                                                     
 1 1.07   34.2 Mbale District Health Office, Maluku, Bishop Wasoke, Mbale City, Bugisa sub-region, Eastern Region, Uganda                
 2 1.01   34.4 Bukigai Health Centre, Bududa Ring, Bukigai, Bugisa sub-region, Bududa, Eastern Region, Uganda                            
 3 1.03   34.4 White Cross Medical Centre, Bududa Ring, Bukigai, Bugisa sub-region, Bududa, Eastern Region, Uganda                       
 4 1.01   34.3 Trinity Medical Centre, Bududa Ring, Namaitsu, Bugisa sub-region, Bududa, Eastern Region, Uganda                          
 5 0.316  32.6 MB Medical Clinic with Lab Services, Mutungo Ring Road, Mutungo, Nakawa, Kampala Capital City, Kampala, Central Region, U…
 6 0.322  32.6 Hope Day Clinic, Kireka Road, Nakawa, Kampala Capital City, Kampala, Wakiso, Central Region, Uganda                       
 7 0.335  32.6 Kinawataka Road, Kiswa, Nakawa, Kampala Capital City, Kampala, Central Region, Uganda                                     
 8 0.335  32.6 Zion Medical Clinic, Kinawataka Road, Kiswa, Nakawa, Kampala Capital City, Kampala, Central Region, Uganda                
 9 0.335  32.6 Kinawataka Road, Kiswa, Nakawa, Kampala Capital City, Kampala, Central Region, Uganda                                     
10 0.334  32.6 Maternity Clinic, Kinawataka Road, Kiswa, Nakawa, Kampala Capital City, Kampala, Central Region, Uganda                   
>
```